# Creating a button using LotusScript agent

Tags: javascript, lotus-domino, lotusscript

In my web application, I am throwing search result on the WQS agent using print statement, everything works fine now my question is that I would like to generate a html button using lotuscript WQS agent on the search result page that would say " Go back to search page" and putting js code like

```
history.goback(-1)
```

Can anyone please help me how to achieve using lotusscript agent ?
I know we can do this using document.write but not sure how to do that. and also i want to put this button on top right corner of the result page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write out the exact HTML that you want to generate, including the [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) event code for your button.  Then put that exact code into a print statement, being sure to escape the quotation marks properly. Put the print statement in the appropriate place in your agent so that it will be positioned at the top right.